# How to read correctly with serialport in node js?

Tags: node.js, arduino, node-serialport

This is the code I have in node js to read from the serial data port of the arduino.

```
var SerialPort = require('serialport');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3000);

var serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4", {
    baudRate: 9600,
    parser: new SerialPort.parsers.Readline("\n")
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.on('message', function(msg){
        console.log(msg);
    });

    socket.on('disconnected', function(){
        console.log('disconnected');
    });
});

var clearData = "";
var readData = "";

serialPort.on('open',function(){
    console.log('open');
    serialPort.on('data', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        readData += data.toString();
        io.sockets.emit('message',data);
    });
});
```

This is the code that I have in Arduino, it's just a short example.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
Serial.println("Hello");
delay(2000);
}
```

However, in the console of node js the following is shown when printing the data:
[image]

How can I get the data correctly in one line?
To have something like this:

Hello

Hello

Hello

Answer (score 2):

I cannot test this end to end (no arduino anywhere near), but since `serialport` seems to implement a Readable stream, I'd try using [`scramjet`](https://www.scramjet.org/) like this:

```
const {StringStream} = require('scramjet');

serialport.on('open', () => console.log('open');
serialport.pipe(new StringStream) // pipe the stream to scramjet StringStream
    .lines('\n')                  // split per line
    .each(                        // send message per every line
        data => io.sockets.emit('message',data)
    );
```

Scramjet would sort the readline issue for you.

Comment: Thank you sir, i was struggling with something similar, and your response helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code with the serial port device that uses RS-232 protocol. Its advantage is that you don't need install the third package from npm.

```
var recVal = '';
mySerial.on('data', function(data) {
  if(data.indexOf('\n') != -1) {
    io.emit('serial:data', {
      value: recVal
    });
    console.log("Data: ", recVal.toString());
    recVal = '';
  } else {
    recVal = recVal.concat(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: I got io not defined. what do you import @zemunkh ? var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);?